# Guice - Testing correct behaviour of injector - getClass() vs instanceof

Tags: junit, guice

I'm preparing a presentation of Guice, where I plan to demonstrate the (correct) behaviour of Guice by executing Unit Tests. In the following test case, I want to ensure that the correct types were injected

```
@Test
public void shouldInjectCorrectDependencies() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ModuleImpl());
    House house = injector.getInstance(House.class);

    Assert.assertTrue(house.door().getClass() == (WoodenDoor.class));
}
```

Now, I wonder which approach would be better:

- Using getClass() to check for a concrete class
- Using instanceof to check for a type (and subtypes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I no expert on Guice, but in Spring DI, you can have instances injected which are not instances of the class you're expecting. For instance, in your example, if `House` is not a class, but an interface, then spring under certain circumstances (for instance if you're using a transaction) gives you a Proxy, not an instance of a class which implements the interface. The only guarantee you have is that it will implement the correct interface. So I would use:

```
Assert.assertTrue(house.door().isAssignableFrom(WoodenDoor.class));
```

Comment: I think that would need to be `WoodenDoor.class.isAssignableFrom(house.door().getClass())` or better `WoodenDoor.class.isInstance(house.door())`... but since you know the type you're interested in at compile time, `house.door() instanceof WoodenDoor` seems best to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reasoning with classes, which is error prone as pointed out by Matthew, why not have the correct class implement a method which, when called, returns the result you expect?

In this case, maybe:

```
public class Door {
    public String getDescription() { return "Wood"; }
}

...

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ModuleImpl());   
Assert.assertEquals("Wood", injector.getInstance(House.class).door().getDescription());
```